# combine 2 half-height video sources into one combined video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam

Using ffmpeg.exe (under Windows) , 
I want to produce a 1280 by 720 pixel video 
that combines half-height -cropped versions of 
two video sources (input streams) 
that are stacked atop one another.

One source is from a webcam, which is set to capture at 1280x720. I want to use the top half of that (top 360 of the 720 lines of vertical).
`video="Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000"`

The other (2nd) source is from
`video="screen-capture-recorder"`

-- I have read many threads online, found via web searches. I am very confused. I could use some hand-holding. I tried the new vstack filter. I don't need pad (padding). I can't find a simple example (command line) that matches what I am looking for.

I added 
`-vf "crop=1280:360:1280:360"`

Maybe the first two values should be different ('`0`'s , maybe ? ) .

I tried placing that portion of the command in different places, relative to the specifications of the input `-f dshow -i "video=[...]"`.

I'm confused by map  (graph) stuff of ffmpeg.

`"[0:v][1:v]vstack[v]" -map "[v]"`

Once I am able to record *video*, I also want to combine with audio. Audio will be from a single source.

I have successfully made many videos using just screen/desktop capture + loopback audio using Windows Direct Show -- in which I record from only a single video source ...

e.g. :

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -framerate 30 -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -filter_complex amix=inputs=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le (output file)
```

---

examples of commands that I have tried, and failed are :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -f dshow -i video="Microsoft LifeCam HD-5000" -vf "crop=1280:360:1280:360" -filter_complex vstack -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast 5000screen_take1.mkv
```

I even tried adding : 
`"[0:v][1:v]vstack[v]" -map "[v]"`
to that , above (previous) command.

Comment: I want a simple example. I don't need any changing of ratio. For example, I found on the new Beta "Video" Stack Exchange website --  http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/ffmpeg-cropped-video-changes-aspect-ratio

Comment: Zeranoe's Windows builds of ffmpeg are from Git sources, but  https://ffmpeg.Zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ doesn't seem to draw from the latest (3.x) branch and  seems to lack the `vstack` filter. I did find, however, "FFmpeg 3.0 Windows Builds" http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/blog/?p=464#more-464

Comment: Is this [your Q](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/17893/1871)?